# Show that, there are no integers $(m, n)$ such that, $m^2 + (m + 1)^2 = n^4 + (n + 1)^4$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics

Show that, there are no integers $(m, n)$ such that, $m^2 + (m + 1)^2 = n^4 + (n + 1)^4$.

Okay so i see that $m>n$ as smaller powers of $m$ are being to compared to larger powers of $n$.
So my first thought was turning the equation into something of the form $negative=positive$ which is a contradiction hence no solutions. Intuitively i feel $m>n^2$ for the same reason mentioned previously. But idk how we can establish that claim.

Show that $x^4 + y^4 - z^4 = 1993$ has no solutions in integers.

Well this one my first thought was congruences and parity (odd/even) as all 4th powers are $\equiv 1 $ modulos $2,3,4,8$ (that is only if they are not divisble by those numbers, point is its either $0$ or $1$.). But well that doesn't seem like the way to start the question though it certainly seems to be useful midway. For beginning the question i thought of maybe rewriting the thing as $x^4 - z^4 = 1993-y^4$ and factor but i dont think that leads anywhere.

Could someone provide beautiful/elegant solutions which helps me learn and understand how to approach such questions?

Comment: For the last one mod $5$ easily works (why?)

Comment: Thanks a ton @Conrad !. I totally forgot that the 4th power $\equiv 1$ hold for mod 5 too !

Comment: For the first equation, how about $m=n=-1$?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the first equation in the form:
$$m^2+m+1=(n^2+n+1)^2.$$
Can you end it now?

I got that it's possible for $m^2+m+1=1$ only.

Comment: Since $n$ is an integer $n^2+n+1$ is also an integer and thus $m^2+m+1=k^2$ for $m,k \in Z^+$ but clearly as $m^2<m^2+m+1<m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2$ and It can't be a perfect square as it lies between two perfect squares of consecutive numbers. I think the question should have mentioned for $m,n, \neq 0$. Isn't it sir @MichaelRozenberg? Beautiful solution as usual :).

Comment: @Aayam Mathur Maybe it means to find a natural solutions or positive integer solutions.

Comment: Yeah i guess coz someone commented and it is true that $m=n=-1$ works too so i guess they meant solutions in $N$.